# Gather files of a similar filename programmatically

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a photobooth that will dump all the pictures as they're taken onto a helper PC on the same network.

On the helper PC, I had planned to have a scheduled task run every x minutes to perform some edits on the images using ImageMagick (eg montage, label, etc).

The files are named via timestamp and it takes 4 at a time, so if a few people back to back used the photobooth, then it would transfer the following files to the helper PC:

- 2016-01-29-22-05-01.jpg
- 2016-01-29-22-05-02.jpg
- 2016-01-29-22-05-03.jpg
- 2016-01-29-22-05-04.jpg
- 2016-01-29-**22-07**-01.jpg (note the timestamp change)
- 2016-01-29-22-07-02.jpg
- 2016-01-29-22-07-03.jpg
- 2016-01-29-22-07-04.jpg

I was initially using a batch file to just serve *.jpg into ImageMagick, but now I realise if two people use the photobooth in < x minutes, then there will be two sets of images (like the above). Handing 8 pictures instead of 4 to ImageMagick will result in a mess.

My question is - how can I identify files which a similarly named (eg, first 16 characters are the same) and just pass these to ImageMagick?

Comment: What if two people use the photobooth within the same minute?

Comment: Good pickup! I just timed it, the end-to-end process is 57 seconds so while it's really unlikely, it's possible. I'll add a couple of 1 second sleeps in to pad it out to min. 1 minute per person.

Comment: Make a new directory (folder) per customer maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\transferred.log"
IF NOT EXIST "%filename1%" ECHO xxx>>"%filename1%"
:again
SET "transfer="
FOR /f "tokens=1-6delims=-" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d /on "%sourcedir%\*.jpg"^|findstr /b /v /g:"%filename1%"'
 ) DO (
 SET "transfer=%%a-%%b-%%c-%%d-%%e"
 GOTO movefiles
)
ECHO no new files to MOVE
GOTO :EOF

:movefiles
>>"%filename1%" ECHO %transfer%
:: don't know what you want from here
ECHO transfer %transfer%* ??
SET "transfer=%transfer%-01.jpg %transfer%-02.jpg %transfer%-03.jpg %transfer%-04.jpg"
ECHO transfer %transfer% ??
:: perhaps a delay here for helper PC to process??
timeout /t 5 >nul
GOTO again
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `filename1` to suit your circumstances.

You haven't told us what happens to the files you want grouped, so I've assumed they remain.

The meat of the matter is the `for` - grab the first 6 tokens using `-` as separators and apply to a directory-list in basic form without directories sorted in name order and filtered for lines that begin with a string which does not appear in `filename1`

If any such line is found, gather the name into `transfer`, and do something with that value (not specified), recording the value in the log so that the next loop includes the value found in its exclude-list.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time to code this, but you could do the following

1. Get current date and time to the second
2. Format it like the filenames (`set mydatetime=2016-01-29-22-07`)
3. `for /r %i in (%mydatetime%*) do move %i %targetpath%`
4. wait 1 minute `PING 127.0.0.1 -n 1 -w 60000 >NUL`
5. loop

(this assumes only one batch per minute as you indicated in the comments above)

However, if you have the ability to modify the output (as indicated by adding "a couple of 1 second sleeps") I wonder like everyone else why you don't just make the output more robust?  Separate folders, batch names, etc.